# Wamp syncing issue

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, synchronization, dropbox

I have 3 PCs with WAMP server installed on all of them. I wanted them to be all in sync, so when i develop a website, i want all the files to be updated on the 3 of the PCs.

After Googling, I came across the famous Dropbox and the Google Drive.
I succeeded in syncing the 3 PCs by pointing my localhost to the Sync folder, etc..

However, when i copied the "data" folder from the mysql folder, i just noticed that there are 3 files, ibdata , ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile2 that are big in size (around 50mb each). And these files constantly grow in size whenever i use the database.

So i don't won't these 3 files to be in sync, because more than 100mb data will be uploded and downloaded everytime.

Google Drive and Dropbox won't let me choose which files not to sync in their selective sync option.

What will be the best solution?

Comment: Dropbox or Google Drive may be doable for files, but probably not for MySQL.

Comment: No, the selective sync option is for folders only and not for files.

Comment: Understood - but what I mean is that as far as syncing MySQL goes, simply syncing the files is a bad idea anyway. You most likely want to look at some sort of replication.

Comment: Use GIT for you projects ;) and put a dump in your repo.

Comment: Are you using INNODB databases?

Comment: RoggsFolly, no I'm not using innoDB

Answer (score 1):

First is a solution even necessary? My understanding is that Dropbox uses a high compression of files while sending, so your 50mb files might be 1mb files or less when sent. (Text and especially MySQL text with repeated syntax is highly compressible.)

Second, about the solution. I suggest using a buffer folder in addition to a local folder sync software. (This last one is where you will be able to filter files.)

Wamp's data folder -> Sync'ed by local directory software to folder#2 (minus what you don't want synced) -> Folder#2 sync'ed by Dropbox / Google Drive.

Almost all local folder sync softwares have fonctionality to setup custom ignore rules so those 50mb files won't be copied to folder#2, and thus won't be sync'ed to your cloud storage.

Not exactly elegant, but as you said Dropbox / Google Drive don't have an ignore list, so it is certein you can't do it that way and will have to go with a less than ideal workaround.